# Weird behavior of compiler - debugger

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

This question / issue is closely related to a previous issue I have shared here. However....

I have a quite large project, to which I am performing unit test and integration test. Unfortunatly, I cannot share the code, other than tiny pieces, and it would be anyway to a large project to share.

I'll summarize at best I can...
A type is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct { 
s32 s32IntLimitHigh; 
s32 s32IntLimitLow; 
s32 s32RegLimitHigh; 
s32 s32RegLimitLow; 
u16 u16IntGain; 
u16 u16PropGain; 
u16 u16IntStep; 
BOOL BOOLFreeze; 
} structPIreg;
```

The type of the single members is quite clear by their names. 
Two arrays are defined as follow:

```
structPIreg expected_VectParPI[VECT_PI_LENGTH];
structPIreg VectParPI[VECT_PI_LENGTH];
```

As it's for unit testing, I have the original variable and its expected value.
The arrays are of 8 elements. 
The

```
sizeof (VectParPI[1]) is 29 :
```

4*s32 + 3*u16 + BOOL = 4*4+3*4+1 = 29 
u16 is 16 bit on the original machine, here on the x86 architecture it's a 32 bit.

I compile, the tests run, and I get weird results. 
So I start a debugging session, and here things get even weirder.

Now, the problem is that the size of the structure of the two variable seems to be different. 
And what I see on the debugger is consistent.

I will post two pictures of the variable watch window to make you understand. 
In this watch window I compute the offset in byte between the second and the first element of the 2 arrays.

```
(char*)&VectParPI[1]-(char*)&VectParPI[0]   long    32  
(char*)&expected_VectParPI[1]-(char*)&expected_VectParPI[0] long    29
```

[watch windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p3GE.png)

As you can see, the offset is different.
But I can't figure why. 
How, in the object file, can the offset/size of two different variables of the same type be different ?

What is more intriguing is that when I start the debugger and the gdb pauses on main, the two sizes are correct (29 each). 
Than I set a breakpoint somewhere, and when the breapoint is hit, I see the sizes at 32 and 29.

How can possible a memory address change ? 
It is like the structure is shifted in the memory. 
I just can't figure why....

As a "proof" that I am not dreaming, I attach the same watch window as before. 
You can see that the eclipse/gdb has highlighted in yellow the size and the offset, because at some point they changed from 29 to 32. 
Funny enough.... :)

[highlighted watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k941m.png)

Comment: Hard to say without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but my guess would be that [__attribute__((packed))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-packed-type-attribute) is used inconsistently.

Comment: Hi, I'll try to come out with a MCVE. There's no __attribute__ whatsoever in the code.

Comment: There is also [#pragma pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html) and [-fpack-struct](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fpack-struct).

Answer (score 0):

> 4*s32 + 3*u16 + BOOL = 4*4+3*4+1 = 29

This is *not* the expected `sizeof` for this structure. Due to padding, the expected `sizeof` is 32.

The reason you are getting `29` is that the structure has `__attribute__((packed))`, and the fact that you are getting two different sizes means that some of your compilation units have the `packed` attribute, and others don't.

That is a violation of the one definition rule, and undefined behavior.

You need to find where this `packed` is coming from, and make it consistent throughout the program.